# Logging value from .class file, intercepting possibly with AOP

Tags: java, logging, aop

Lets say I am using some existing java library, and I only got .class files. But not getting the result I am expecting. So I look at the source code, and see that there is some logic there, and want to see if my correct values reach the library code.

Can I log the values that reach the .class files somehow? Was thinking of AOP..?

**Method from external library.**

```
public void updateValues(String value, MyClass classValue)
```

For example I see this line in source code, and when this is ran, I want to intercept it, by like writing the `value` and `classValue` to log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have the source code so why just don't debug it?

But anyway - it is possible using `AOP`. You need to have that `.jar` file in your classpath. Lets say that you have already configured your `AOP`, then all you need to do is:

```
<aop:pointcut id="yourPointCut" expression="execution(* package.to.your.class.YourClass.updateValues(..))" />
```

This pointcut will allow you to log the values of the `updateValues` method.

Comment: Well I have the .jar file, and I attached the source code to it in eclipse. I think I must recompile the code everytime, when I make changes and then copy the package to my maven folder everytime, and somehow disable maven from auto updating the library. Seems like alot of effort, so thought about AOP.

Comment: I have never used AOP, so I don't have it configured....can i use AspectJ or something? I just know it exists, but have no clue really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AOP to do that, specifically AspectJ with

- either compile-time binary weaving (weaving advice into your target JAR, generating a new version of it)
- or load-time weaving (which would not alter your JAR, just the Java classes within the JVM).

The AspectJ docu is quite good. It is not rocket science, just a new concept at the beginning. So it might take a little while to wrap your head around it, but then it is an elegant and powerful tool.

Comment: load-time weaving is like osgi? I don't have to restart my service?

Comment: Read some introductory material, please. And no, chocolate is not like snow. ;-)

Comment: haha, ok thanks :) so , load-time weaving is something like jrebel? it changes bytecode?